# TFS 2015 Migration to different service provider

Tags: tfs-2015

I am looking at performing a TFS 2015 migration from one site (i.e. service provider) to another.

The 2 sites are completely different companies and therefore different domains and hardware.

This TFS has been used for work items and source control.

I see that Microsoft has the following articles that seem to be related to this:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/move-clone-hardware 
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/move-across-domains

I have a ton of questions then as I try to sort this one out including:

Is what I am trying to do reasonable... first follow the instructions in the 1st link and then follow the instructions in the 2nd link? I ask this since it would appear to me that what I am attempting is actually not really covered by these documents.

For example, in my scenario there may be no mapping from one user to another for a user that has checked in code. So, does this approach handle this ok?

When I searched stack overflow I see that the closest question to mine is this one which refers to a migration tool on CodePlex that is no longer supported:

[TFS to TFS Migration Tool - domain issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654863/tfs-to-tfs-migration-tool-domain-issues)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's reasonable. What you want to do is both changing domains and physical servers which called environment-based move and hardware-based move.

You should not try to combine an environment-based move with a hardware-based move. **First *complete* the hardware move, and then change the environment.** Detail steps just follow the tutorials above in your question.

Comment: Thanks! I will know soon how well this goes.

Comment: well... turns out this does NOT work. That is, as I was worried, since this is a completely different domain (i.e. different service provider and so there is no communication between the 2 domains) the restore fails with: "TF400998: The current user failed to retrieve the SQL Server service account information from OLDSERVER. Please make sure you have permissions to retrieve this information." I am going to attempt to manually restore the SQL Server databases and go from there I guess :(

Comment: that is, as per "https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/move-clone-hardware" it says "As an alternative, you can create an instance of SQL Server on a server that already has a matching version installed and restore the TFS databases to that instance, but that will require more post-restoration configuration." This is what I will attempt next